# Having difficulties fetching data on React using fetch

Tags: reactjs, cors, fetch

I've been trying this end-point but I can't make a fetch.
On postman and the web-browser I get data, but not the case with fetch using React

this is the end point:
http://monedaextranjera.ansolidata.com/data/?format=json

the Error says:

> Access to fetch at 'http://monedaextranjera.ansolidata.com/data/?format=json' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I tried using fetch and axis

Comment: I'm not familiar with axis. Do you perhaps mean axios? Also, there are thousands of questions about CORS errors on this site. It's hard to believe none of them would help you. Click on the [tag:cors] tag to see a list of them.

Comment: headers: {
                 "Content-Type": "application/json",
                 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
                 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            }, if it's your server you should  replace * with the same Origin of you server just like so : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://example.com"

Answer (score 0):

set the fetch property to mode: 'cors'

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode)

```
fetch('http://monedaextranjera.ansolidata.com/data/?format=json', {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                 "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body:....
 })
```